Reading PNG data regarding
I am trying to read PNG data with libpng, but I am not able to figure out the last step.
I am trying to read png pixel data. Here is what I came up with
#include <png.h>
#include <pngconf.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BYTES_TO_CHECK 8

// checks the file and returns the file pointer
FILE *check_png(char *file_name) {
    char buffer[BYTES_TO_CHECK];
    FILE *fP = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if (fP == NULL) {
        printf("FILE NOT FOUND!");
        exit(0);
    }
    fread(buffer, 1, BYTES_TO_CHECK, fP);
    int check = png_sig_cmp(buffer, 0, BYTES_TO_CHECK);
    if (check == 1) {
        printf("NOT A PNG");
        exit(0);
    }
    return fP;
}


int main() {

    png_structp png_ptr;
    png_infop info_ptr;
    png_uint_32 height;
    png_uint_32 width;

    printf("ASCII Generator\nPlease Enter the PNG file name\t");
    char file_name[100] = "google.png";
    /*scanf("%s", file_name);*/
    FILE *fP = check_png(file_name);

    png_ptr = png_create_read_struct("1.6.44", NULL, NULL, NULL);
    info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);

    if (png_ptr == NULL)
        printf("ERROR PNG POINTER IS NULL");

    else if (info_ptr == NULL)
        printf("ERROR INFO POINTER IS NULL");

    png_init_io(png_ptr, fP); // initialising input output
    png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, BYTES_TO_CHECK); // tells that some bytes are already read

    png_read_png(png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY, NULL);   // reads png

    height = png_get_image_height(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    width = png_get_image_width(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    printf("%d %d", height, width);

Now to read pixels value I am having some issues
png_bytep row_pointer[height];
png_read_image(png_ptr, row_pointer);

Returns Read Error and it aborts. Then I tried
png_bytepp row_pointer = png_get_rows(png_ptr, info_ptr);

Which returns a array of pointers to the pixel data for each row, but it is all null.
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        printf("%s", row_pointer[i][50]);
    }

I also tried png_read_rows but to no avail.

png_uint_32 width; ...  printf("%d %d", height, width); hints you are compiling without enough compiler warnings.  Consider enabling all warnings to let the compiler help you more.

First of all, you are passing info_ptr without getting some meaningful data to it. You have no error checks for the functions returns.
Why did not you just see an official example of libpng, and base your code on it? You are obviously missing some parts of an example code.
The extract from example code of libpng
                  png_uint_32 width, height;
                  int bit_depth, color_type, interlace_method,
                     compression_method, filter_method;
                  png_bytep row_tmp;

                  /* Now associate the recently opened (FILE*) with the default
                   * libpng initialization functions.  Sometimes libpng is
                   * compiled without stdio support (it can be difficult to do
                   * in some environments); in that case you will have to write
                   * your own read callback to read data from the (FILE*).
                   */
                  png_init_io(png_ptr, f);

                  /* And read the first part of the PNG file - the header and
                   * all the information up to the first pixel.
                   */
                  png_read_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

                  /* This fills in enough information to tell us the width of
                   * each row in bytes, allocate the appropriate amount of
                   * space.  In this case png_malloc is used - it will not
                   * return if memory isn't available.
                   */
                  row = png_malloc(png_ptr, png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr,
                     info_ptr));

You can visit a official repository example and base your code on it.
